# How to create a Google Maps with draggable routes with fixed markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api

I have a webapp where I show a route on a map, I pass two address and show the route on map, so I'd like that this route should be draggable but the points A and B shoud be fixed. How to do this?

Comment: Please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778201/array-to-create-multiple-routes-on-google-maps-v3

Comment: +1 example http://www.geocodezip.com/inventoresdegaragem_com_dbteste_indexB.html